# UINavigationBar make always with blur effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

On iOS 16 at least when you scroll `UITableView` navigation bar becomes with blur. But when we don't have any scroll, how to force `UINavigationBar` be with blur?

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's so common question, but I can't find answer. All answers is too old.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your insights, and if I'm not mistaken, you want the appearance of your UINavigationBar to always have a blurred effect, even when there is no content underneath it.

### iOS 13

UINavigationBar has a property called `appearance()` that lets you configure the appearance of the navigation bar based on a `UINavigationBarAppearance()` class.

This class lets you configure all properties related to the navigationBar, including its appearance.

When a navigation controller contains both a navigation bar and a scroll view, the scrollEdgeAppearance takes effect if part of the scroll view's content appears underneath the navigation bar; otherwise, the standardAppearance properties apply.

If you configure both to have the same effect, the navigation bar won't transition, and the effect will persist.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let navAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    navAppearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navAppearance

    return true
}
```

This way, the navigation bar will always remain blurry.

Keep in mind that the blurry effect on a navigation bar without any content underneath it, will result in the background color with an alfa value applied.

[standardAppearance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czyde.png)

[scrollEdgeAppearance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F3b4.png)